# ActiveMQ embedded broker force to listen to ip instead of hostname

Tags: activemq-classic

We use an embedded ActiveMQ broker and create it like this(a bit simplified) :

```
BrokerService brokerService = new BrokerService();
brokerService.addConnector("tcp://1.2.3.4:61610");
brokerService.start();
```

The problem we have is that the broker is listening to the hostname instead of the IP-address and this does not work in our case. How can I force the brokerService to listen on the IP address instead of the hostname.

Here is what the log says when starting the broker:

```
2015-01-20 15:16:03,414 qtp833534789-27 INFO  BrokerService - Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0 (b1653842572, ID:ABC123-59162-1421763362756-0:1) is starting

2015-01-20 15:16:04,948 qtp833534789-27 INFO  TransportServerThreadSupport - Listening for connections at: tcp://myhostname.mydomain.local:61610

2015-01-20 15:16:04,948 qtp833534789-27 INFO  TransportConnector - Connector tcp://myhostname.mydomain.local:61610 started
```

Comment: tried editing transport connector field in activeMQ.xml?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it still says Listening for connections at: tcp://myhostname.mydomain.local:61610

Answer (score 1):

A TCP listener can never listen to a DNS name. It's always bound to one or many interface(s)/IP address(es).

In this case, ActiveMQ helps you out by reverse resolving the DNS name from the IP because it's easier to understand what's going on in the logs when you read a logical DNS name rather than some number.

ActiveMQ has some code like this

```
protected String resolveHostName(ServerSocket socket, InetAddress bindAddress) throws UnknownHostException {
    String result = null;
    if (socket.isBound()) {
        if (socket.getInetAddress().isAnyLocalAddress()) {
            // make it more human readable and useful, an alternative to 0.0.0.0
            result = InetAddressUtil.getLocalHostName();
        } else {
            result = socket.getInetAddress().getCanonicalHostName();
        }
    } else {
        result = bindAddress.getCanonicalHostName();
    }
    return result;
}
```

To replace the IP with a DNS once the socket is indeed bound. I guess you have not even tried using the IP address, since it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
brokerService.addConnector("tcp://0.0.0.0:61610");
```